# Inline assembely read word and double word from IO port

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, kvm

I have a segmentation fault after the **inw** command in the following code:

```
    n=0;
    unsigned short port_in = 0;

    set_dr7(0x60000480);
    asm volatile("movw %0, %%dx \n\t"
                 "outsw \n\t"
                 : : "i"((short)(TESTDEV_IO_PORT + 3)), 
                 "S"(st1));          
    asm volatile("inw %1, %0\n\t" : "=a"(port_in) : "i"((short)(TESTDEV_IO_PORT+3)));
```

I have tried in, inl and more... but i still have a segmentation fault.
When I tried inb with port_in declared as unsigned char - it doesn't have segmentation fault - but I need **inw** and **inl** for another test.

What is the problem in my code?

Generally I'm trying to add a test to the kvm-unit-test.

Comment: Assuming you're doing this in Windows or Linux, and you're running this as an application, you probably don't have privileges to do port I/O like `in`, `inw` or `inl`. These are *privileged* instructions that you cannot use in *user mode*.

Comment: @lurker not entirely true, you can use them in linux user mode if you got the privileges (`root` or `CAP_SYS_RAWIO`) and you use `iopl` or `ioperm`.

Comment: @Jester right, thanks for that. I had neglected that case.

Comment: Assuming you are running this in the kernel, you are also changing dx in the outsw without letting the compiler know.  Either add it as a clobber, or (better yet) change your input from "i" to "d" and get rid of the "movw".  And since outsw reads memory, I'd consider adding the "memory" clobber.